# Clicking hyperlink changed value of cell on different worksheet to link cell's value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with full price offers and a seperate worksheet which makes alterations to this price based on factors such as condition.

Since there is quite a large amount of full price offers, I thought an easy way would be to make each price a hyperlink which copies to a cell in the worksheet with price adjustments, where the prices will automatically adjust.

I'm not really good with VBA, but I've conjured up a basic code.

```
Dim ClickCell As String

Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Sh.Name = "Book 1" Then
        If ClickCell = "A3" Then
            Sheets("Book 2").Range("B2").Value = "Sample Data"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Book 1" Then
        ClickCell = Target.Address(False, False)
    End If

End Sub
```

The main problem with this code (I'll be able to change the IF statement to a range to cover the entire column containing prices), is that I can't fetch the value of the cell containing the hyperlink and paste it to cell B2. ActiveCell.Value only seems to copy the value of B2 (the cell where the price should be pasted, essentially replacing the value of that cell with itself), and BeforeDoubleClick didn't seem to work for me at all.

Finally, I've been running this code as a Workbook module since it runs across different worksheets, is that right?

Edit: Asked to provide data samples (I'm not sure if this is right).

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eqaf.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9jMO.png)

Comment: add some data examples

Answer (score 0):

Target contains the cell in which the Hyperlink is located. You can get the location from Target.SubAddress (see comments in code):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim subAddress() As String

    If Sh.Name = "Book 1" Then
        ''.SubAddress is for example 'Book 2'!B2
        ''Get sheet name by splitting into an array by delimiter !
        subAddress = Split(Target.subAddress, "!")
        ''Trim ' from the first item
        subAddress(0) = Replace(subAddress(0), "'", "")

        Sheets(subAddress(0)).Range(Target.subAddress).Value = Target.Range.Value
    End If
End Sub
```